# Bootstrap 4 HTML - remove rounded corners from parallax jumbotron

Tags: css, bootstrap-4

I've got a great looking parallax going for a home page, but I would like to remove the rounded corners from the images.

Here is my html for one section:

```
<div class="jumbotron paral paralsec1">
            <h1 class="display-3">Connect</h1>
            <p class="lead">with musicians in your area.</p>
            <p class="lead"><a class="btn btn-info btn-lg btn-md" href="/public/register_member/" role="button">REGISTER AS MEMBER</a></p>
        </div>
```

And the CSS:

```
.paral {
min-height: 800px;
background-attachment: fixed;
background-size: cover;
background-position: 50% 50%;
}
```

Does anyone know how to remove the rounded corner with a minimal of changes to my code?

Comment: There are no images in your code example. Please provide a [mcve]. Also, have you tried changing the `border-radius` of any of the elements?

Answer (score 5):

You can use the `rounded-0` `class` to remove the `border-radius`, [check the docs](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.1/utilities/borders/#border-radius)

In your case, that would be like this:

```
<div class="jumbotron paral paralsec1 rounded-0">
  <h1 class="display-3">Connect</h1>
  <p class="lead">with musicians in your area.</p>
  <p class="lead"><a class="btn btn-info btn-lg btn-md" href="/public/register_member/" role="button">REGISTER AS MEMBER</a></p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3):

Add rounded-0 attribute to remove border radius.

Answer (score 0):

Answered my own question... I had to override a border radius. Like so:

```
.paral {
min-height: 800px;
background-attachment: fixed;
background-size: cover;
background-position: 50% 50%;
border-radius: 0px;
}
```